# PHP - how to add different times

Tags: php

I want sum of 3 different times.

Ex:

```
h1 = "04:23";
h2 = "04:16";
h3 = "00:00";
```

So answer should be `$hours = "08:39"`

I have searched for that and got many solution but not getting right answer.

Here is my code:

```
$hours = strtotime($h1) + strtotime($h2) + strtotime($h3);
$total_hours = date("H:i", intval($hours));
echo $total_hours;
```

`"00:00"` is the answer which am getting for above code. I don't want to use any user define function which can add times. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You want time or the total hours & minutes?

Comment: Total hours and minutes.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a built in method. But what is wrong with calculating the total time?

Comment: I have read somewhere that calculating total time is not a good way and there is some way to get summation of times but I don't know that way.

Comment: If the logic & code is correct then I dont see there is any problem with that.

Comment: You need `hour:min:second` format

Comment: Why don't you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6019598/5701450)

Comment: Okay! Thank you! can you tell me how can I calculate total hours without built in method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum N number of time (HH:MM Format) ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681725/how-to-sum-n-number-of-time-hhmm-format)

Comment: @Akshay no I just need `Hours:Minutes` because seconds are not there in my times which need to be calculated.

Comment: what happens if you remove the intval and just use $hours?

Comment: @mirko911 I got the error `date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given in`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine HH:MM:SS with HH:MM:SS in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262126/combine-hhmmss-with-hhmmss-in-php)

Comment: @User7 your version works for me  php -f test.php 08:39#

Comment: @mirko911 I found that solution from SO but didn't work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want total time and hours so no need to work on strtotime or date() method. 
There isn't any inbuilt method for this solution. 
I always use this solution.

Working Demo for your solution : https://eval.in/98249

```
function sum_time() {
  $i = 0;
  foreach (func_get_args() as $time) {
    sscanf($time, '%d:%d', $hour, $min);
    $i += $hour * 60 + $min;
  }
  if ($h = floor($i / 60)) {
    $i %= 60;
  }
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $i);
}

echo sum_time('04:23', '04:16', '00:00');
```

Comment: *I don't want to use any user define function which can add times*.

Comment: @SougataBose. yeah i read it on question but there isn't any way i have spent a lot of time for this logic but it's not possible so many possibilities are there like when day change  etc. so above solution is the solution  as per my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use user-defined logic, your only option is to use built-in function which is `strtotime` as per my opinion. But you need to provide right format to `strtotime` function which is like `00:04:16`. I've provided my logic to give you the solution.

```
$h1 = "04:23";
$h2 = "04:16";
$h3 = "00:00";

$h_arr = array($h1, $h2, $h3);

function sum_time($h_arr) {
    $hours = 0;
    $minutes = 0;
    foreach($h_arr as $value) {
        $value_explode = explode(':', $value);
        $hours += $value_explode[0];
        $minutes += $value_explode[1];
        if($minutes > 60) {
            $hours += 1;
            $minutes = $minutes % 60;
        }
    }

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
}

echo sum_time($h_arr);
```

The logic provided by **Bhavin** is also good. If you're comfortable with it, you could go for that. It's up to you.

**Demo**

With your test cases - https://eval.in/703528

Other test cases - https://eval.in/703529

Answer (score 0):

Bhavin and Perumal93 answer working fine. But i am thinking different way.I am trying to do this as simple as possible. Code look like below:

```
<?php
/**
 * @param array $times
 * @return string
 */
function sumOfDiffrentTime($times = array())
{
    $minutes = '';
    // loop through all the times array
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);
        $minutes += $hour * 60;
        $minutes += $minute;
    }
    $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
    $minutes -= $hours * 60;

    // returns the  formatted time
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
}

$times = array();

$times[] = "04:23";
$times[] = "04:16";
$times[] = "00:00";

// pass your $times array to the function
echo sumOfDiffrentTime($times);
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://eval.in/703658)

Hope it will helps you.